# is it possible to hardcode data to Array objects in java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Can some one correct this statement for me?

```
List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<Object>();
objectList.addAll(Arrays.asList(["206C(1)", "CG", 1],["206C(1)", "SG", 1]));
```

after getting this data in objectlist i need to use .stream() like operations

Object will be a class of

```
public class Object{
 private String section;
 private String code;
 private Boolean yn;
getters and setters 
}
```

any help is truly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In general a class' name should give an idea of the class' content/purpose. That is such generic names as `Object` are a bad idea in most cases. Additionally `Object` might easily get confused with `java.lang.Object`...

```
public class MyObject {
  private String section;
  private String code;
  private Boolean yn;
  //getters and setters

  public MyObject(String section, String code, Boolean yn) {
    this.section = section;
    this.code = code;
    this.yn = yn;
  }
}
```

With the above constructor you can do:

```
List<Object> objectList = List.of(new MyObject("206C(1)", "CG", true), new MyObject("206C(1)", "SG", true));
```

If you make a static import for a factory method, you can save some characters:

```
public class MyObject {
  // all of the above

  public static MyObject of(String section, String code, Boolean yn) {
    return new MyObject(section, code, yn);
  }
}
```

```
import static MyObject.of
...
List<Object> objectList = List.of(of("206C(1)", "CG", true), of("206C(1)", "SG", true));
```

Comment: thanks for the fast reply, this is working but is there a way to omit `new MyObject(` every time when i add a new data as there are around 80 object data in my project

Comment: You could create a factory method with a shorter name. But in general 'no'. I'll update the answer-